# How to Ctrl + CapsLock = CtrlLock in autohotkey

Tags: autohotkey

I want to press `Ctrl + Capslock` which will toggle lock the `Ctrl` state.

**For Example,**

If I press `Ctrl + Capslock`, then if I keep clicking google search results on chrome, each result will open in a new background tab or if I wish to save a pdf file I will simply press `s` instead of `Ctrl + s`

If I wish to disable this behavior, or in other words, unlock the `Ctrl` key, I can press `Ctrl + Capslock` again.

**In other words,**

`Ctrl+Capslock` combo will make it such that the `Ctrl` key is always pressed down without me actually pressing it. Redo-ing the combo un-presses `Ctrl` again.

I have seen this achieved [here](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/14218-crtl-lock-like-caps-lock-with-autohotkey/) but using the `Ctrl` key itself.

I've tried modifying that version, however it is not working

```
Hotkey, ^CapsLock, Lock
return

Lock:
GetKeyState, state, Control, T
if state = D
Send {Control Down}
else
Send {Control Up}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the control toggling function runs while the user is still holding control, so the function will always see control as being in the down state. To solve this, I suggest storing the "control lock" toggle state in a variable and waiting for control to be physically released before performing the function. Put together it looks like this.

```
#SingleInstance, force
crlock = false

^CapsLock::
    KeyWait, control, u
    IfEqual, crlock, false
    {
        Send, {Control Down}
        crlock = true
    }
     else
    {
        Send, {Control Up}
        crlock = false
    }
Return
```